# How can i install a language pack

Tags: magento2, language, language-package

So i have a custom theme on magento 2.1 and im trying to install Greek as a second language on it. So i found this. http://107.170.242.99/download.php 
And it declares that i have to do this : 
"Download file corresponding to your language. It is a single file, that contains translations and module context. Easiest to download it to your installation root directory. Now run the following command:

```
bin/magento i18n:pack -m replace -d source_[lang_code].csv langpack [lang_code]
```

where [lang_code] is language code like pl_PL.
As a result, a directory langpack will be created that contains proper structure of language files for your installation. Copy it over to your Magento installation and the translations should be visible. If not, run the following commands to clear cache:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [lang_code]
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Note: additional directory i18n contains strings for which the module could not be found in your installation. This file can be skipped."

the problem is when i try this command via ssh "`bin/magento i18n:pack -m replace -d source_[lang_code].csv langpack [lang_code]` " i get this answer from the server. **[RuntimeException] Not enough arguments.** Anyone care to help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be install Greek language via composer.
Look at this repo https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-greek-language-pack. Just follow steps in readme.

Install Greek pack:

```
composer require mageplaza/magento-2-greek-language-pack:dev-master
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy el_GR
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Their instructions erroneously include a `langpack` argument that isn't necessary/suppported.

This command, however, still fails:

`php bin/magento i18n:pack -m replace -d source_el_GR.csv el_GR`

Apparently the provided `.csv` file has errors. You'll have to contact the vendor to get more info.